# When onclick on the edittext in a listview using custom arrayadapter, Error occur

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, listview

When I try to click the EditText in the ListView by following code, the apps stop and error occurred.

The custom arrayadapter is using to adding RelativeLayout into list view

RelativeLayoutListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.justfortest;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class RelativeLayoutListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RelativeLayout> {

Context context;
List<RelativeLayout> layoutItemList;
int layoutResID;

public RelativeLayoutListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
        List<RelativeLayout> listItems) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutItemHolder layoutHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        layoutHolder = new LayoutItemHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        layoutHolder.layoutcontect = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_content);


        view.setTag(layoutHolder);

    } else {
        layoutHolder = (LayoutItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    RelativeLayout dItem = (RelativeLayout) this.layoutItemList.get(position);

    layoutHolder.layoutcontect.addView(dItem);  //This is Line 52

    return view;
}

private static class LayoutItemHolder {
    RelativeLayout layoutcontect;
}
}
```

here is the ActivityMain:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            layoutlist = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.container);

    layoutlist.add(CreatLayout());
    layoutlist.add(AddTakes());
    layoutlist.add(AddTakes());
    adapter = new RelativeLayoutListAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_container,layoutlist );

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

public RelativeLayout CreatLayout(){
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    /*--Adding TextViews, EditTexts, RadioButtons in RelativeLayout layout dynamically--*/
return layout ;
}
public RelativeLayout AddTakes(){
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    /*--Adding another set TextViews, EditTexts, RadioButtons in RelativeLayout layout dynamically--*/
return layout ;
}
```

when I click the EditText the error occur and code is here

```
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234): Process: com.example.justfortest, PID: 12234
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at                android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3759)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3612)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3557)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3533)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at com.example.justfortest.RelativeLayoutListAdapter.getView(RelativeLayoutListAdapter.java:52)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2733)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1348)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1619)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2546)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:429)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2245)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1967)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6383)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-30 02:19:16.136: E/AndroidRuntime(12234):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just couple of things as comment, your stack trace says there is error in your `RelativeLayoutListAdapter` class line no 52. It would be good if you could highlight in question which line it is. And I also noticed you are creating your listview in some weird way. You actually need to inflate the relative layout with ids of its components. I don't see that happening in your adapter class.

Comment: uhm…yes its quite weird, because i just want to put different relativelayout with different component into the listview. because i want to have a swipe left listener in the addtakes layout. and i will finally put a horizontal scroll view at the end of it.

Comment: okkk. and what is line 52 in your adapter class? and by the way in how many relative layouts are you planning to put the components dynamically?

Comment: there will be three type of RelativeLayout will be adding
1. CreatLayout() //it will add once only
2. AddTakes() //the no. of adding will defind by customer
3. a HorizontalScrollView in a Relativelayout  //add once only

Comment: i dont know how to high light :(
so i mark a comment on line 52

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but I don't actually understand what is the point of first creating a listview that contains three dynamic relative layouts and then adding view again dynamically to three of those relative layouts. You could simply use View to create it.

Comment: I would have a LinearLayout (Main/parent view) and have three Relative layouts (subviews) in it and then inflate each of those relative layouts whenever i want.

Comment: actually what i did before is using a scrollview to be the parent of all component in creatlayout and addtakes, which only a void method befor.
after i found that i need to have a horizontalScrollView to setup my final component in the activity, it tell me a problem that horizontalScrollView cant add into a scrollview...
that's why i want to have a listview to collect all my component

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the crash is:
The Relative layout present in the ArrayList is getting added to The layout more than once.

Your approach for dynamically adding edit/radio button isn't right.

ListView has Three components

1. Data:That you wan to the user
2. View: UI through which you want to show the data(visual representation of data)
3. Adapter: the peice of code that connects data to the UI

Listview generally contain homogeneous Views(Thus android renders only the number of views required to fill the screen after which point scrolling only recycles the same views,but fills it different data supplied by the ListItems. All of this happens in the getView method.

If you observe there is a convertView passed into getView method ,this is the view that can be recycled.

Now you have used List (Which is UI) as Data

Your code should be appear like this
I have not executed this code. I would strongly recommend you to look into android SDK/Samples
You have to get lot of concepts right.

Main Activity 
`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layoutlist = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
     mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.container);

    layoutlist.add(CreatDataSet());
    adapter = new RelativeLayoutListAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_container,layoutlist );

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
   DataSet CreateDataSet()
{
   DataSet data=new DataSet();
   //data.setRadioButton(true);
   //data.setEditBox(true);
}

class DataSet
{
boolean radioButton;//getter and setters
boolean editBox;/getters and setters
int viewType;//This tells what kind of view this data represents
}
```

`

Adapter code:(This is the place you would bind the data to the view)

```
    public class RelativeLayoutListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RelativeLayout> {

Context context;
List<DataSet> layoutItemList;
int layoutResID;

public RelativeLayoutListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
        List<DataSet> listItems) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutItemHolder layoutHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
       view=createDynamicLayout();
       LayoutItemHolder layoutItem=new LayoutItemHolder();
       layoutItem.rb= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
       view.setTag(layoutHolder);

    } 

     LayoutItemHolder holder =view.getTag();
     //holder.rb

    return view;
}

public int getViewTypeCount()
{
return ;// Return the number of different tyoes of views
}

public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
return layoutItemList.get(position).getViewType();// the type of view for the current position
}

//The purpose of layout holder is to do all findviewbyids only when the createDynamicLayout is called
private static class LayoutItemHolder {
    EditView e;
    TextView t;
    RadioButton rb;
}
}
```

Comment: yes i have radio button in the CreatLayout method,
but the radio button work prefectly,
only the edittext will return error

Comment: that mean i cant use adapter to add a relativlayout to listview?